# Splash Screen not full screen in android device flutter. Tried everyting. Using flutter_native_splash

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

[Flutter Splash Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34wsY.jpg)

Pubspec.YAML code-

```
flutter_native_splash: ^2.0.1+1

flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets/images/splashScreen.png
  color: "#c988be"
```

Styles.xml -

```
style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
         Flutter draws its first frame -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Is the problem that there is a white band around your image, and you would like the image to go to the edges of the screen?

Comment: yes. u know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide the action bar you need to go to app manifests and then set the theme of the splash screen layout to no action bar as so:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

if you want also to hide the status bar you use flags in the splash screen activity as so:

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
    }else{
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check this package [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash), in this package you just need to set your splash screen image path.

Add this code into your pubspec.yaml file

```
flutter_native_splash:
  background_image: "assets/images/splash_bg.png"
```

Make sure to run this command:

```
flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Android does not have good support for filling the screen without distorting the image.  One way you can fix this problem is to make the splash screen image larger than it needs to be, set it as centered, and then the splash image will be clipped by the size of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

When you config flutter_native_splash like this: 
[image]

After run command: "flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create", flutter_native_splash  package will generate some drawable files on android/ios folder like below:

[image]

In android, to display that image in fullscreen. open generated launch_background file and change gravity="center" to gravity="fill"

[image]

After modify gravity, run your app again, you will see splash screen displayed as full screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

hello Vietnamese compatriot Trung Đoan, in my case just leave the "image: assets/splash.png" is fine, add

```
<item>
  <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/splash"/>
</item>
```

in launch_background.xml file, and do the rest as you said, thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

There are two places you need to change the command to get full screen splash and it **worked for me**

First in the *android\app\src\main\res\drawable\launch_background.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="fill" android:src="@drawable/background"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="fill" android:src="@drawable/splash"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Second in *android\app\src\main\res\drawable-v21\launch_background.xml*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="fill" android:src="@drawable/background"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="fill" android:src="@drawable/splash"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

In both if these files earlier the android:gravity was "center" and change it to "fill" it will be fixed
Also no need to again then run the *flutter pub run* command as it will again reset the following the their earlier values

Answer (score 0):

Using Flutter Native Splash, edit your pubspec.yaml in this way:

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#c988be"
  image: assets/images/splashScreen.png
  fullscreen: true
  android_gravity: center
  ios_content_mode: center

  android_12:
    color: "#c988be"
    image: assets/images/splashScreen.png
    fullscreen: true
    android_gravity: center
    ios_content_mode: center

  web: false
```

Then run this command in your terminal:

```
flutter clean && flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create
```

I created tutorials on creating Flutter splash screen with and also without libraries. This will definitely help you.

[Flutter splash screen without using any libraries](https://youtu.be/MCosWsD5yKc)
and [Flutter splash screen using Flutter Native Splash](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GV19Hawgpeg)